# Creating a storyboard with posing

Tags: animation, keyframes, audio

*Background: I've worked with Blender a lot in the past, but all I really did was create models. I never had to use it to animate or render anything. I basically never touched the cameras and lights, either.*

I plan on working on a short with some friends of mine, who are animators. For this very short short, I'm also the "writer", meaning I plan out all the scenes. I want to make sure I convey the scenes I have in my mind to my animators as accurately as possible.

Instead of writing down and describing everything in meticulous detail, I want to create a little storyboard to make it easier on everyone. Not all of them have English as their native language (like me! In case it wasn't obvious), and I want to make sure there are no misunderstandings. Plus, it's a lot easier to simply show it, instead of describing it - if you can.

However, I suck at drawing. So what I wanted to do, since it's a lot easier for me to do than it is to doodle some embarrassing and possibly unclear sketches, is to use the models and pose them for the key frames. We already have the models with rigs, and I can always use placeholder models for things we don't have yet.

The problem is, I'm a bit stumped. I don't know where to begin. As I said in the beginning, I never used the camera, I never animated anything and I certainly never rendered anything. I know about the poser edit mode, but that's about it. Where do I start?

Just to give you an idea of what I want to do in the animated storyboard:

- use existing models and pose them for key frames
- use the camera a bit to move around, to show how the camera should move in the short
- add a simple drawing for the parts that require detail that the models can't provide, such as very specific facial animations (one of my friends helps out in that)
- use some sounds and music here and there
- quickly render what I have as a video

Might be too much to ask here, but most tutorials I've seen go into waaaaay too much detail, as they (rightfully) assume the viewer will need that info. Is there a specific way to make a storyboard like that in Blender?

Comment: You will need to learn at least the basic usage of camera placement, rigging and posing to do that. Like all software it will require you to invest some time and getting comfortable with the tools. Don't expect a single post teaching you how to do this. Blender might be the tool you need, or maybe not. It all depends on your ability. If you struggle with the program, then you will not be as creative as you might want to be. Consider other tools as well. Do some research into [makehuman](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/), posetool3d storyboarder and similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are achieved through SCENES. Create a new Scene (which is like a giant collection of things) place everything in your settings, your render outputs, your render camera, your objects, duration (timeline) for each scene and thus creating SCENE 02, SCENE 03...etc..
[image]

For quick sketches and simple drawing you can use the grease pencil, that allows you to make markings in a 3 dimensional space.

Once you have set the timing, framing, layout of elements, etc..
CHANGE THE WORKSPACE TO VSE (Blender video EDITOR).
Hover the timelines and SHIFT+A (ADD A "SCENE" STRIP), and then choose the ones you have created.
THE VSE EDITOR MUST EXIST IN A NEW EXCLUSIVE SCENE (name it VSE SCENE) so that it can contain all other scenes.

The rest is up to you to edit, cut, trim SCENE clips, just like you would in an animated storyboard.