# Are there any placeholder models included with Blender?

Tags: modeling

Sorta related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132268/creating-a-storyboard-with-posing). Long story short, I want to pose models so I can use them as the base for my drawings. For some of the drawings, I don't need specific models. A regular, featureless human figure (male or female) would do. Does Blender come with any such "basic" models? Or is there a quick way to create a simplistic human figure with realistic proportions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender does not natively have humanoid characters installed, but MB-Lab is an open source Blender add-on (v2.79 and v2.8) - creates rigged, textured human characters

https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/